# AJAX in codeigniter doesn't find base URL

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter-3

And my other question is that, is the code correct, will my AJAX request get to my controller ?

Here is the relevant parts on the code:

My view (I have this on a POST form cause I want to send the data on another table) :

```
<script> var base_url = <?php echo base_url(); ?> </script>

<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Apartament</label>
<select onchange="showUser(this.value)" name ="txtApartament1" class="form-control">
    <?php foreach($getEntry as $value) { ?>
    <option><?php echo $value->apartament ?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

In the same view this is my AJAX part:

```
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtApartament1").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtApartament1").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", base_url + "usercontroller/ajaxp?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

And this is my controller - usercontroller.php function:

```
public function ajaxp(){
echo "received";
}
```

I will get this error:

> (index):257 Uncaught ReferenceError: base_url is not defined
>   at showUser (localhost/adminigniter1/:257:29)
>   at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (localhost/adminigniter1/:205:89)

My project filename is codeigniter1!

I did not set any config file on codeigniter. should I ? Anything else?

Comment: did you load url helper.

Comment: base_url is function not variable.It should be base_url()

Comment: Yes Hek: $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form');

Comment: Paul: I changed, still same error!

Comment: @Anakin Vader try below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this..

1.Load url helper using `$this->load->helper('url')` or in `applicaiton/config/autoload.php.`

2.Set base_url config item in `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'your_url';
```

3.In your script.Remove `var`.Because it creates variable as `local`.So you can not use inside function.

```
base_url = <?php echo base_url();
```

**OR**  put it `var base_url = <?php echo base_url(); ?>` inside  `showUser()` function.

**UPDATE**

```
var url = base_url + "usercontroller/ajaxp?q="+str; //OR  var url = <?php base_url();?>+"usercontroller/ajaxp?q="+str;

console.log(url);

xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: If I will do it like this: <script>base_url = <?php echo base_url();?></script>, I will get Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : on the source - > <script>base_url = http://localhost/adminigniter1/</script>, and when I will select I will still get the undefined base_url(and I have all the url in my config folder).

Comment: try base_url inside function

Comment: Not it seems that I won't get the url problem, but I still get the problem with the ":" token after http, when I generate my link from url on the source response : base_url = http: //localhost/adminigniter1/. I would also get now : (index):203 Uncaught ReferenceError: showUser is not defined(…)

Comment: see update and what is output on `console.log(url);`?

Comment: Hmm, the second option OR// seems to kinda work, I will get now (index):258 GET http://localhost/adminigniter1/NaN56 404 (Not Found) and from the console.log NaN56. So that means 56 is not a number ?

Comment: try using send valid number.

Comment: Where I have to put valid number ?

Comment: use just `var url = <?php base_url();?>+"usercontroller/ajaxp` and see ajax status on network tab of console.success or error.for testing